# Electron + Purescript + thermite

Tags: bower, electron, purescript

I've been looking at putting together a simple electron app using purescript and purescript-thermite but I've run into a snag with require not finding the react library which was installed through bower. Here is the error message that I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (...snip.../electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...snip.../electron-quick-start/output/React/foreign.js:4:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...snip.../electron-quick-start/output/React/foreign.js:166:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

The react library is located in bower_components/react/... but that doesn't seem to be on the search path. Is there some way that I can add it to the search path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either

- install React as an NPM module (this will require using something like Browserify if you're running the browser)
- shim the `require('react')` call somehow at the top level